# Existence of a left-limit on a continuous convex function over an open interval

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following question. Given that $\phi$ is a continuous function on $[a,b)$ and convex on $(a,b)$, show that $\lim_{t \to b^{-1}} \phi(t)$ exists as an extended real number in $(-\infty,\infty]$.

I have already shown that $\phi$ is bounded below on $[a,b)$, giving that the limit could not equal $-\infty$, otherwise at some point in $[a,b)$, arbitrarily close to $b$, $\phi$ would not be bounded below. I am struggling to show that the limit does exist however.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\phi$ is convex, the function
$$
\psi(t) := \frac{\phi(t) - \phi(a)}{t - a},
\qquad t \in (a,b),
$$
is non decreasing, hence it admits the limit as $t \to b^-$, and this limit belongs to $(-\infty, +\infty]$.